# ajax return data in database out of order

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, mysqli

```
function selectDiv() {
<?php
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, name  FROM data");
$stmt->execute(); 
$stmt->bind_result($id ,$name);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {?>
    add (<?php echo "'$id'";?>,<?php echo "'$name'";?>);
<?php } ?>
}

function add (id , name) {
    $.post("type.php",{id:id, name:name}, function (data) {
    add2 (id, name, data);
}); 
document.getElementById("div").innerHTML += name + "<br>";
}

function add2 (id , name, type) {
    document.getElementById("div").innerHTML += name + "|"+ type + "<br>";
}
```

I retrieve data from data base using $.post and on each turn I call function add to append a certain div. the problem is that the data comes out of order. How can I fix it? please help

Comment: Did you try "SELECT id , name  FROM data ORDER BY id"?

Comment: the problem is not with the database. I think the problem is with the $.post call, but I do not know how to fix it.

Comment: Where's the $.POST call then?

Comment: This sounds like a PHP problem, not Javascript. Try to order the collection before the while.

Comment: @ErickLangfordXenes how can I do that ?

Comment: @MCMXCII sorry I have just edit my question

Comment: Try to make all $.post calls in one. This will solve your problem.

Comment: @ErickLangfordXenes I have thought about that, but then I will need to loop again over them in the second the function. I want to have a faster code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this if is possible:

```
function selectDiv() {
 <?php  $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id , name, t2.type  FROM data INNER JOIN t2 ON join_condition1”);
 $stmt->execute(); 
 $stmt->bind_result($id ,$name);
 while($stmt->fetch()) {?>
 add (<?php echo "'$id'";?>, <?php echo "'$name’”;?>, <?php echo "'$type’”;?>);
 <?php } ?>
 }

function add (id , name, type){
document.getElementById("div").innerHTML += name + "<br>" + "|"+ type + "<br>";
}
```

Comment: it is not possible as type is in another table

Comment: then use join. This is the faster way.

Comment: is it possible when each name have multiple type records?  type return as an array for each name.

Comment: still in that case you can concatenate the type records into a json array format and then in the javascipt iterate over the collection. This is faster than make multiple ajax calls.

Comment: Make only one Ajax call.

Comment: A loop iteration is going to be faster, you can test it; also the other problem with multiple ajax calls is that they dont finish in the order you expect.